# CollectionView with Expander not finding property although works outside of expander header

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a C# WPF project and I am trying to using a CollectionView to group elements together.

The data is read in via an XML message stored within an array.

Below is the code I am using to process the array:

```
public void processCallLogInfo(string xml)
        {
            List<CallLogInformation> callLogInformationList = new List<CallLogInformation>();
            string phoneNumber = null;
            string contactName = null;
            string contactPhoto = null;

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            var callLogInformationRoot = doc.Descendants("CallLogInformation");
            foreach (var callLogInformation in callLogInformationRoot)
            {
                var callLogRoot = callLogInformation.Descendants("CallLog");
                foreach (var log in callLogRoot)
                {
                    var logRoot = log.Descendants("LogInformation");
                    foreach (var info in logRoot)
                    {
                        CallLogInformation callLogInfo = new CallLogInformation();
                        callLogInfo.contactInformation = new ContactInformation();
                        phoneNumber = info.Element("PhoneNumber").Value;

                        if (info.Elements("ContactPhoto").Any())
                        {
                            callLogInfo.contactInformation.photoBase64String = info.Element("ContactPhoto").Value;
                        }
                        if (info.Elements("ContactName").Any())
                        {
                            callLogInfo.contactInformation.contactName = info.Element("ContactName").Value;
                            callLogInfo.contactNameOrPhoneNumber = info.Element("ContactName").Value;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            callLogInfo.contactNameOrPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
                        }

                        callLogInfo.callType = info.Element("CallType").Value;
                        callLogInfo.date = long.Parse(info.Element("Date").Value);
                        callLogInfo.callDuration = Int32.Parse(info.Element("Duration").Value);
                        callLogInfo.contactInformation.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

                        callLogInformationList.Add(callLogInfo);
                        //iCallLogManager.addCallLogItemToGUI(callLogInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
            iCallLogManager.addArrayToGui(callLogInformationList);
        }
```

Below is the CallLogInformation class

```
public class CallLogInformation
    {
        public enum CallType { INCOMING, OUTGOING, MISSED, UNKNOWN };
        public string contactNameOrPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public ContactInformation contactInformation {get; set;}
        //public CallType callType { get; set; }
        public string callType { get; set; }
        public long date { get; set; }
        public int callDuration { get; set; }

        public CallLogInformation()
        {
            //callType = CallType.UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
```

Below is how the array added to the collection view

```
public void addArrayToGui(List<CallLogInformation> callLogInformationList)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
                {
                    ICollectionView callLogView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(callLogInformationList);
                    callLogView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("callType"));
                    lstCallLogInformation.ItemsSource = callLogView;
                    return null;
                }), null);
        }
```

I am trying to group by callType property so the calls are grouped as INCOMING/OUTGOING/MISSED

When I put the expander part of code in it says that it can't find property callType but if I remove the expander and just add the callType to the list group without the expander it works, so callType is definetely working so I don't understand why when the expander is used it has a problem.

Below is the WPF XAML

```
<ListView Height="397" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="491,29,0,0" Name="lstCallLogInformation" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding callType}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle />
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding contactNameOrPhoneNumber}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding callType}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you define groups using the GroupDescriptions, your view object
>   (a CollectionViewSource object or an object that derives from
>   CollectionView) wraps each group in a CollectionViewGroup object.
>
> So, when you custom the groupstyle, you are dealing with
>   CollectionViewGroup objects. Your can still access your original data
>   type via Items property of CollectionViewGroup. That "Name" is a property of CollectionViewGroup Object.

Orginal source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/731a3230-65db-497e-afbb-6bb9f8b378d5/listview-grouping-with-expander?forum=wpf

Perhaps try `{Binding Name}` instead of `{Binding callType}`. As the comment said, "Name" should refer to CollectionViewGroup.Name, whch should map eventually to callType.

If you need more information, you have been given `CollectionViewGroup.Items`, which should have all the necessary items for that specfic group.

Comment: Thanks, I did see that in the docs, I thought name was an element within the object they were using. Instructions aren't overly clear. Thanks for your help with this